# Get the Total Number of Sales for an Ubercart Product Using Views in Drupal 6?

Tags: mysql, drupal, view, report, ubercart

I have a site where I sell products using Drupal 6 and Ubercart 2. Each product is provided by, and referenced to, an external creator, and that person gets a percentage of each sale.

I used CCK fields to create a User Reference field and Commission field that is a plain text number (i.e. '60' for 60% commission rate)

I am creating a Views page where the provider can log in and see the total number of sales, total money amount of all the items sold, their commission % for that product, and the total money they will received.

I have set up all the calculations using PHP and the Customfield module for everything else, I just need to know how to pull the total number of sales for any given product using Views.

I originally thought the Ubercart order product: Qty field would do it, but that pulls the qty sold in a given order, or something like that.

The Ubercart report page at /admin/store/reports/products shows the total sales for each product, so I know it's possible, but I am not good enough at programming to see how they did it.

I think it should be pretty straight forward for an experienced user.

Anyone?

Comment: It looks like I need to count the total number of rows in the uc_order_products table when the "nid" column equals "whatever the node id is", and at the same time, only do so when the order_status column for said "nid" is set to "completed" in the uc_orders table. But I don't see a "nid" column in uc_orders :-/ Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Line 219 from uc_reports.admin.inc might help? `$sold = db_result(db_query("SELECT SUM(qty) FROM {uc_order_products} AS p LEFT JOIN {uc_orders} AS o ON p.order_id = o.order_id WHERE o.order_status IN $order_statuses AND p.model = '%s' AND p.nid = %d", $model, $product['nid']));`

Answer (score 3):

I DID IT! I can't believe I figured it out. Line 219 from uc_reports.admin.inc was the key though.

Here is what I did to get the total # of sales for a given product.

In my View, I created a Node ID field and excluded it from the display. Then I created a Customfield PHP Code field and used the following code, where $data->node_vid pulls the Node ID from the field I created initially.

```
<?php
$sold = db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {uc_order_products} AS p LEFT JOIN {uc_orders} AS o ON p.order_id = o.order_id WHERE o.order_status ='completed' AND p.nid = '$data->node_vid'"));
print $sold;
?>
```

I then created a few more Customfield PHP Code fields with some basic PHP math functions to produce what I needed in the other fields.

I used $data->customfield_phpcode_3 to pull the total sales data into the other fields, your specific number might vary. The only thing to watch out for here is that if you delete one of your other Customfield PHP Code fields, you will have to go back and change $data->customfield_phpcode_3 to whatever new number it needs to be.

It all seems easy as pie now that I look at it.